# PHP extending class properties

Tags: php, class, mysqli, extend

I have two classes in a PHP application, B extending A for example.
Class A has a function which returns some of its other properties in the form of an array of SQL insert queries eg

```
Class A {
$property_a;
$property_b;
$property_c;
$property_d;

function queries() {
$queries = array();
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO xxx VALUES " . $this->property_a . ", " . $this->property_b";
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO yyy VALUES " . $this->property_b . ", " . $this->property_d";
}
}
```

I would like class B to have a similar (identical) function which does the same thing for class B's properties, whilst still maintaining the values from class A.  The idea being that each query will be passed through a final function all at the same time ie:

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach($queries as $query) {
if(!$mysqli($query)) {
$mysqli->rollback();
}
}
```

IF all OK $mysqli->commit();

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?
Any advice and ideas appreicated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within B::queries() you can call the [parent](http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim)'s implementation of that method and append your data to the array a::queries() returns.

```
class B extends A {
  protected $property_e=5;
  public function queries() {
    $queries = parent::queries();
    // In a real application property_e needs to be sanitized/escaped
    // before being mixed into the sql statement.
    $queries[] = "INSERT INTO zzz VALUES " . $this->property_e;
    return $queries;
  }
}
$b = new B;
foreach( $b->queries() as $q ) {
  echo $q, "\n";
}
```

But you might (also) want to look into an ORM library like e.g. [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks,
One more question.  Is it possible to extend this process even further?

eg to have a class C which can access its parent function as well as its parent's parent function?Hope that makes sense lol

Comment: c::queries() calls its parent's implementation (B::queries()) which calls its parent's implementation (A::queries()). A::queries() returns an array, B::queries() adds its elements and returns the  array, C::queries() appends its elements and returns the array. This can go on forever if you like ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter function to grab the properties in queries(). In each class you can then control what values the queries function is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really carry over stuff from one instance to another without initializing the newer class with the other instance's information. So you can extend A to change B's query function contents, then initialize B with an A instance:

```
class A {
    protected $propa = "";
    protected $propb = "";
    //etc

function query { /*...*/ }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct( A $classA )
    {
        $this->propa = $classA->propa;
        // etc
    }
    function query()
    {
        //B-type queries
    }
}

$A = new A();
// set stuff in a
new B( $A );
```

If A and B are 100% the same (including query function), just clone A:
   $a = new A();
   $b = clone $a;

Answer (score 0):

so you want to use the properties in class A and class B? 
you can do this by using parent.
in class B:

```
function queries(){
  $queries = array()
   //stuff to get queries

  return array_merge($queries,parent::queries());
}
```

Comment: You couldn't use parent::$property to get property values on an instance of a class. You could do this with static classes, but it is unlikely that this would lead to the desired result.

Comment: that's not what I'm doing at all. I'm calling a parent method, not a value.